# byte[] to string and String to byte[] keeping information unchanged

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have the byte array of a string.

> How to convert `byte[]` to `String` and `String` to byte[]

After compressing I get the compressed value in form of byte array.
`byte[]` value at `System.out` is

```
h?ö\
É·ë’YO¸p˜à¼Œ[ä”½"$žQºÍCïÎ·fØzöÛBi¤!<
```

How can I convert this byte array value to `String` keeping its value unchanged and then getting it back to byte array for decompressing?
tried buitin functions but they change the whole compressed byte array

Comment: You need to take character encoding into account.

Comment: Any one can Provide me with the list of char set so I can try out

Comment: I got this hopefully I will manage to do It
http://www.unicodetools.com/unicode/codepage-latin.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ISO-8859-1 when converting bytes to String and back

```
    String s = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
    bytes = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Comment: that's a string version of the id of an object array, not the bytes it contains.

Comment: got This one is the best answer amongst all

Comment: er. you shouldn't need that.  What are you actually trying to do (where does the input come from?)

Comment: It comes from a text compression algorithm which compress the text, using it to reduce the size of data transferred.
You can better try to do this and if it returns the same It is close to a miracle :-p

Answer (score 1):

try `new String(byteArray)`
and `string.getBytes()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the char set for your `byte[]` array while decoding from raw into string.

The String type contain such constructor `String(bytes, Charset charset)`

Comment: What type of character set it can I have tried up with the available like utf-8

Comment: detecting character encodings is /hard/.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] b=new byte[10];
b[0]=100;
b[1]=101;
b[2]=102;
b[5]=0;
b[6]=0;

String st=new String(b);
System.out.println(st);//def
b=st.getBytes();
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
    System.out.println(b[i]);
}
```